# OpenLayers Caculate distance between two coordinates gives wrong answer

Tags: openlayers

I have a GPX file and I am trying to calculate the total distance between two points with the following function

```
import { LineString } from 'ol/geom'

getDistance(previous, next){
   const coords = [ previous, next ]
   const line = new LineString(coords);
   return line.getLength();
},
```

I know `getLength()` is supposed to return in meters but I am getting some very small numbers and when I add all distances I am nowhere near the 2.6km of the gpx file.

my data looks like this : `[[0.194655, 38.730435], [0.194435, 38.730522]]` and the distance I am getting for this is `0.0002365776828023007`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output seems correct to me, it's the length of the linestring in degrees.

To get the distance in meter, try `getDistance` of `ol.Sphere`

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getDistance

edit: you are confusing the `getLength` method of LineString with the `getLength` method of ol.sphere